# How to handle exceptions in function app having ms-rest-azure with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-function-app

I have created a function app in azure portal having Nodejs of v12 as runtime environment.

I am able to login with service principal name and secret as follows:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log("Started Execution");
    msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain, function(err, credentials) {
       if (err) return console.log(err);
       var client = new someAzureServiceClient(credentials, 'subscriptionId');

       if(req.body.action ==="xyz") {
         client.someOperationGroup.method(param1, param2, function(err, result) {
           if (err) {
             context.res = {
               status: 500,
               body: "Error: " + err
             }
           }
           context.res = {
             status: 200,
             body: "action executed" + result
           }
         });
       }
       else {
         context.res = {
           status: 500,
           body: "failed"
         }
       }
     });
     context.res = {
       status: 200,
       body: "Done" // Output
     }
}
```

The problem is context variable is not accessible inside and I am not able to handle the response. The output of above method is "Done" always no matter what the execution failed or succeed.

Comment: So where is the potential error that you cannot catch?

Comment: @AvivLo after logging using service principle and performing some operation if the error comes I am not able to catch it but it is executing correctly.

Comment: The `concept` variable is still accessible inside for sure according the scope of the variable. It's just that there might be some problems with your `if(req.body.action ==="xyz")` Does `req.body.action` exists or it's sometimes `undefined`. Is the data type of `req.body.action` String. Watch out for the strict equality operator.

Comment: I am passing the request parameter that was not the problem, my code was executing only the context variable not getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acess the context variable inside other calling only by removing the async from function declaration and use context.done() when you done with the response. Your code will look like this afte change.

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
context.log("Started Execution");
msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain, function(err, credentials) {

   context.log("===Here you are able to access context under this call=====");

   if (err) return console.log(err);
   var client = new someAzureServiceClient(credentials, 'subscriptionId');

   if(req.body.action ==="xyz") {
     client.someOperationGroup.method(param1, param2, function(err, result) {
       if (err) {
         context.res = {
           status: 500,
           body: "Error: " + err
         }
       } else {
           context.res = {
             status: 200,
             body: "action executed" + result
           }
        }
        context.done();
     });
   } else {
     context.res = {
       status: 500,
       body: "failed"
     }
     context.done();
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: thnx. I found out shortly about how to exporting the function in this thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node